# create docker compose file

Tags: wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy

How can I make docker-compose.yaml where:
The input is nginx as a reverse-proxy
A wordpress application is running behind it
Mysql database is running for it
In this case, wordpress connects to mysql at 127.0.0.1
The --network=host option is not allowed

my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:beta-php8.2-apache
    container_name: wordpress
    hostname: wordpress
    restart: always
    networks:
      - service-network
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    container_name: db
    networks:
      - service-network
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - service-network
#    links:
#      - wordpress
#    volumes:
#      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
 

volumes:
  wordpress: {}
  db: {}

networks:
  service-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of one

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=must_be_eight_characters
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=must_be_eight_characters
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
    networks:
      - app_bridge_network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - app_bridge_network
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    networks:
      - app_bridge_network

networks:
  app_bridge_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Go to the official image documentation to see the configuration requirements for [Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) and [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

Wordpress will then be able to reach mysql, through the bridge network. Note: The bridge network isn't actually required but since you asked specifically about communication I have included it. If you were to run the containers in different compose files or from different `docker run` commands then the bridge network would be required for communication between the containers on the host i.e without leaving the host.

In this example, Wordpress would communicate to the database via `db:3306`. You could prove this works by executing a curl from the nginx container.

```bash
docker exec ${container_id} /bin/sh
curl db:3306
```

The output is `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed` which basically means the request reached mysql but was an incorrect request.

Comment: maybe I didn't express myself correctly
I need the line WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
change to WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1:3306
how would it be implemented?

Sorry if the question seems stupid